# Constraining the params returned by statsmodels logit to positive values

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression, statsmodels

As the title suggests I am trying to restrict the params returned by statsmodels logit to positive numbers. So I played around with different methods in scipy.optimise which logit uses and their args like bounds etc but couldn't figure out how I can do this. Any suggestions? Any other module with logistic regression which restricts weights to positive numbers?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Well I have some features which are logically similar even though they don't have much correlation and I feel like any link between the difference between them and the target value is spurious